# How to show table from MySQL database using php and html

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect my html page with MySQL database to show data from one specific table to my page, but I always get an error actually it just goes to die part of an SQL code. I am really new to PHP programming so please can someone help me, what am I doing wrong?
 Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AJDE</title>
</head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "select * from PERCENTILE";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(!$result) {

    die ("Umro!");

    }
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Forget to select database name!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to show the table as a HTML table or just an array?

The following is what I did to display my table as a HTML table:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '*****';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$selectedTable = 'whateverTableYouWant';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);
if (!$conn){
    die('cannot connect to mysql');
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM $selectedTable";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn , $query)) {

    echo("<div class = 'data_wrapper'>");

    // Display Header of the table

    $fieldcount=mysqli_num_fields($result); //value = number of columns

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);     //Fetch a result row as an associative array:

        //array to string conversion

        echo("<table id='example' class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>");

        echo("<thead> <tr>");

        foreach($row as $item){

            echo "<th>" .$item. "</th>";
        }

        echo("</tr> </thead>");


        //Footer
        echo("<tfoot> <tr>");

        foreach($row as $item){

            echo "<th>" .$item. "</th>";
        }

        echo("</tr> </tfoot>");



        //Display Data within the table
        echo("<tbody>");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($row as $item){
                    echo "<td contenteditable = 'true'>" . $item . "</td>"; //Change contenteditable later
                    //Editable data should be constricted, int = numbers only, string = words, date = date
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo("<tbody>");
        echo "</table>";
        echo("</div>");

    }
```

The following is just displaying as an array:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '*****';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$selectedTable = 'whateverTableYouWant';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

if (!$conn){
    die('cannot connect to mysql');
}
 $query = "SELECT * FROM $selectedTable";

 if ($result = mysqli_query($conn , $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       print_r($row);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank u so much! Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad I can help! Good luck on your project! :D

Answer (score 0):

Please change the connection string like mentioned below.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Please let me know if you've any queries.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to select a database where you will run the query:

Try with this code:

```
<?php
$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with (so replace the database name examples)
$selected = mysql_select_db("examples",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PERCENTILE");

//fetch the data from the database and display results
//replace id,name,year with the columns you have on your table PERCENTILE and you want to show
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "ID:".$row{'id'}." Name:".$row{'name'}."Year: ". $row{'year'}."<br>";
}
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Hope it helps,
Vince.